# Can Not Copy a SQLite Database from Assets to Another Area

Tags: java, android, libgdx

For some reason, I am not able to copy my software's SQLite database from the " assets " folder to a different destination.  With the " copyDatabaseFromAssets() " method I am using, it only produces an empty file.  I did trim the following code so that it would be easier on me to find error messages.

Since I ran low on ideas, [I used an old article from ReignDesign.com](https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) to tweak the database file a bit.  I also happen to be using a 2016 version of SQLDroid, which does appear to work fine.

The file is in " ~/assets/database/test.db ".

Here is the basic code I am using:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        copyDatabaseFromAssets( this, "test.db", true );

    }


    /**
     * Copy database file from assets folder inside the apk to the system database path.
     * @param context Context
     * @param databaseName Database file name inside assets folder
     * @param overwrite True to rewrite on the database if exists
     * @return True if the database have copied successfully or if the database already exists without overwrite, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean copyDatabaseFromAssets( Context context, String databaseName, boolean overwrite )  {

        File outputFile = context.getDatabasePath( databaseName );


        if ( outputFile.exists() && !overwrite ) {

            return true;

        }

        outputFile = context.getDatabasePath( databaseName + ".temp" );
        outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();


        try {

            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open( databaseName );
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream( outputFile );


            // transfer bytes from the input stream into the output stream
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
            int length;

            while ( ( length = inputStream.read( buffer ) ) > 0 ) {

                outputStream.write( buffer, 0, length );

            }

            // Close the streams
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            outputFile.renameTo( context.getDatabasePath( databaseName ) );

        } catch ( IOException e ) {

            if ( outputFile.exists() ) {

                outputFile.delete();

            }

            return false;

        }

        return true;

    }


}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your db file located at inside sub-folder, better way to get file from sub-folder just change this line

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open( databaseName );
```

To:

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("database/" + databaseName);
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Good catch!  Thank you.